# Why does std::set_difference not remove duplicates?

Tags: c++, stl

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) states that `std::set_difference`:

> Copies the elements from the sorted range [first1, last1) which are not found in the sorted
> range [first2, last2) to the range beginning at d_first.

With that said, I would expect the following MWE to output `2 4`, because only 2 and 4 are not in the second set.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> A{1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4};
    std::set<int> B{1, 3};
    std::set<int> difference;
    std::set_difference(
        A.cbegin(), 
        A.cend(), 
        B.cbegin(),
        B.cend(), 
        std::inserter(difference, difference.end())
    );

    std::for_each(difference.cbegin(), difference.cend(), [](int n) {
        std::cout << n << " ";
    });
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

However, it appears that this outputs `1 2 3 4`, and I'm not fully sure why. It does what I expect if I change `A` to only contain `1 2 3 4` Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: The paragraph right after the one you cite says: Equivalent elements are treated individually, that is, if some element is found `m` times in `[first1, last1)` and `n` times in `[first2, last2)`, it will be copied to `d_first` exactly `std::max(m-n, 0)` times.

Comment: Blah. I can't believe I missed that. Thank you. If you post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @ollien Honestly, if you're expecting the C++ standard library to be intuitive and easy to use, you're using the wrong programming language.  It's built for library writers (few of whom seem to have made *their* libraries intuitive and easy to use, either).   I have an objection list a mile long to various standard library features and non-features, and I can't find user-centric explanations for any of it.

Comment: @Tumbleweed53 -- the C++ standard library provides **tools**, not final solutions. Those tools help you construct the things you need, rather than providing a set of specialized things that you have to fight with if you're trying to do something slightly different.

Comment: @PeteBecker Fair enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sure there's a good reason it *has* to be defined to work that way, but it definitely is how it's defined. The standard specifically requires this behavior. Here's the wording as of N4835 (§[set.difference]/6):

> Remarks: If [first1, last1) contains m elements that are equivalent to each other and [first2, last2) contains n elements that are equivalent to them, the last max(m − n, 0) elements from [first1, last1) is copied to the output range, in order.

Comment: I would say logic is to preserve `union(A, B) == difference(A, B) + difference(B, A) + Intersection(A, B)`. and as modulo, there are several options.